# ProcessBuilder can't find file?!

Tags: java, batch-file, processbuilder

Another question in quick succession but this has to be a really obvious error that I am not seeing. I've written some code to run a batch file below but I'm getting an error message saying it cannot find the file but I can assure you that the file does exist in the directory!

```
public class Pull {

public void pullData() throws IOException {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("adb.bat");
    File f = new File("C:\\");
    pb.directory(f);
    Process p = pb.start();  
}

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     Pull pull = new Pull();
     pull.pullData();
 }
```

}

and here is the error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "adb.bat" (in directory "C:\"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: So, adb.bat is in c:\, right? try placing it or a copy of it in the project folder

Comment: doesn't work there either. Am I using processbuilder correctly?

Comment: Have you tried executing the contents of the batch file as the arguments to your `ProcessBuilder`?  E.g., if "adb.bat" does something like "java -version", have you tried doing something like `new ProcessBuilder("java","-server")`?  I'm wondering if Java is trying to treat adb.bat like an executable, even though it's really just a text-based script.

Comment: Have you tried including the path in the constructor (eg, `new ProcessBuilder("c:\\adb.bat")`? See http://www.coderanch.com/t/517098/java/java/Working-ProcessBuilder-working-directory

Answer (score 13):

I'm running Linux, but the same error occurs when I run your code (modified to run a .sh rather than .bat).

Try:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("c:\\adb.bat");
```

Apparently using `ProcessBuilder.directory` doesn't affect the working directory (*for the purposes of discovering the executable*) that was chosen when the builder was constructed (at least, that's what seems to happen. The docs say it will change the working directory, so I guess input/output files might be relative to that?)

I'm not sure what it's actually doing internally, but providing the path to the executable in the constructor fixed the problem.

This post [talks about the problem and this solution](http://www.coderanch.com/t/517098/java/java/Working-ProcessBuilder-working-directory), but also raises whether environment variables have to be set, of which "path"-like variables might be useful to help `ProcessBuilder` discover an executable.

Comment: On Linux, if a `command` is in `directory`, and using the `ProcessBuilder` to change to that directory, when just executing `command` will fail, but executing `./command` tends to work. So the process builder is changing into the directory, but one needs to specifically execute `./command` in that directory, unless the directory is on the `$PATH`.

Answer (score 2):

Hi try to use the tutorial here - http://www.javabeat.net/examples/2007/08/21/using-the-new-process-builder-class/.  Using it I have changed your class a bit and it finds the file (note that I don't know what is inside so can't fully test it).  It compiles and runs without problem, while your own I experience same problems as you:

```
public class Pull {


public void pullData() throws IOException {
    /*ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("adb.bat");
    File f = new File("C:\\");
    pb.directory(f);
    Process p = pb.start(); 
    */
    ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\adb.bat");
     p.start();
    System.out.println(p.toString());
}


 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


     Pull pull = new Pull();
     pull.pullData();

 }


}
```